# Impact Speed of a car

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, kinematics

A car (Mass 4500 Kg) hits a concrete Block (1000 Kg) on left edge. After impact, block rotates in circular motion and stops at about  24 feet from its initial position. How to calculate force with which car hits the block and speed of the car at the time of impact?

Comment: I'm sure friction plays a huge part, if the collision occurred on an ice sheet surely the block would travel much further.  The question must be making assumptions about the coefficient of friction on - say a tarmac - surface.

Comment: Also what is the car doing after the collision? It takes a higher impact force to have the car "bounce off" the wall vs. stick to it.

Comment: -1 Insufficient information.

Answer (score 1):

So with the assumption that the entire kinetic energy of the car transferring to the block and then being absorbed by friction entirely as work you state the fundamental balance of energy

$$ \frac{1}{2} m v^2 = \mu M g x $$

where $m$ is the mass of the car, $v$ the speed of the car, $M$ the mass of the block, $x$ the distance traveled and $\mu$ the assumed coefficient of friction between the block and the road.

This will give you the speed of impact $v$, and the impacting momentum $m v$. The impacting momentum is going to be absorbed by the impact force over a small period of time $T$ with the relationship

$$ m v = \int \limits_{0}^{T} F(t)\,{\rm d}t $$

where $F(t)$ is the impact force as a function of time. If you know that time $T$, then you can calculate the *average* impact force

$$ F_{average} = \frac{m v}{T} $$

The time is a tricky value to calculate because it depends on the material properties and the geometry of the problem. An estimate can be made if you know the approximate stiffness $k$ of the contact (in terms of force/distance). The base harmonic response of the system (impact-rebound) happens in time $$T = \pi \sqrt{ \frac{m^\star}{k} } $$

where $m^\star$ is called the reduced mass of the system. For two point masses this would be $m^\star = \left(\frac{1}{m_1} + \frac{1}{m_2} \right)^{-1}$. In our case the block is hit eccentrically and the reduced mass of the system is

$$ m^\star = \left( \frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{M} + \frac{\ell/2}{I} \right)^{-1} $$ where $\ell$ is the length of the block and $I$ is the [mass moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia) of the block. For a thin slender block $I=\frac{m}{12} \ell^2$ producing the relationship $$m^\star = \left( \frac{1}{m} + \frac{4}{M} \right)^{-1}$$